# Store and execute application installer installer from Azure as in Shared directory

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have to a scenario where I need the flow in the following order :

1. I will have two program installer saved in azure .

a) One is a WPF application binary folder (contains exe and dlls). The entire size is approx. 2-3 MB.

b) Another is a application installer (Contains Setup.exe and other ) The entire size is in GBs (Say SQL software)

2. The User is presented with a web page he logs on to. This will be a ASP .NET MVC Azure site. After login he clicks a link. This link has to download the entire folder (a (above)) and save to temp folder on the client machine and invoke the WPF application exe file. This presents a windows application screen. the user enters some more parameters into the screen and clicks ok
3. The WPF application then calls the SQL setup.exe (b (above)) passing some parameters, to install the application on local machine.Note in this case I do not want to download but just run it directly from the source location

All this needs to work from azure over internet.I have worked with Azure Services and websites but have not worked with storage, so I needs some help in that.

What I am not sure is how I should use the files and what Azure service is most suited for my scenario. I explored Azure blobs as well as Azure File Storage but somehow not able to proceed further.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is: You want to download an installer from Azure? You want to *run* the installer from Azure? Assuming it's about downloading: What have you tried (aside from exploring blobs in general)? Right now, you have no code or programming question. And you're asking about what services to use in Azure (that part is off-topic, but also doesn't really make much sense in this context either). Please edit your question with more clarity.

Comment: The first case (a), I want to download from my ASP .NET Azure service and run in client machine. In the second case (b) I want to execute it directly without downloading (Something like you would if you want to execute from a shared directory). I am planning to build a MVC website for the webpage, but I am not sure what storage type should I use for this scenario. That was the specific question.